# Detecting Enter key

Tags: vb.net

According to my theory this code should work but it does not, its in Visual Basic in the 2019 Visual Studio. The code gives a windows ding but does not fail, I cant understand why it wont work.

I have a textbox1 and a webbrowser1 controls on a form, the textbox1 you enter a url and when key"Enter" is detected I want the code to tell the webbrowser1 control to navigate(textbox1.text)

The code is simple yet baffling, the code which will compile.

```
     Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
      If e.KeyCode = Keys.KeyCode.Enter Then
        Me.Text = TextBox1.Text
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
      End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: replacing the If with : If e.KeyCode = Keys.KeyCode.Enter Then  :works but still windows ding sound

Comment: You don't want the windows ding sound?

Comment: No I do not.  Its like the error noise windows makes, nothing written on keydown but wondering if its keydown or keyup causing the noise.

Comment: `e.SuppressKeyPress = True`

Comment: Where is `Keys.E` defined? and since when does `E`=`Enter`? Do you really mean `e.Key` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to AJD and all the other who have replied and edited.
It seems the correct way to do it is.

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyValue = Keys.Enter Then
        Me.Text = TextBox1.Text
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    End If
    End Sub
```